# /usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 1: /etc/environment: JAVA_HOME: not found

Tags: java, environment-variables, jdk, jre

I'm trying to install **nginx**.

By Running : `apt-get install nginx`

it fails throwing a strange error saying that there is no **JAVA_HOME**

Lokking to my `/etc/environment` file , it looks like this :

```
JAVA_HOME = "/opt/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/" 
JRE_HOME = "/opt/jdk1.8.0_144/jre"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$JAVA_HOME:$JRE_HOME"
```

Since it's already existing , **is there any suggestions ?**

Comment: And what does `echo $JAVA_HOME` output?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen : absolutely nothing ( but the directory /opt/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/  ,  exists )

Comment: And `echo $JRE_HOME`?

Comment: similarly like java_home

Comment: Change `JAVA_HOME = "/opt/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/"` to `JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.8.0_144/"` remove the space between `JAVA_HOME` and `=`

Comment: I fail to see how this is an NGINX error.  Something is missing, and you don't give us any useful data on the actual error you're seeing other than it's complaining about `JAVA_HOME`.  It's probably an unrelated error, so I'm removing the `nginx` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please fix your path syntax, remove the spaces around `JAVA_HOME` and `=` operator.

Change:

```
JAVA_HOME = "/opt/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/" 
JRE_HOME = "/opt/jdk1.8.0_144/jre"
```

To:

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.8.0_144/" 
JRE_HOME="/opt/jdk1.8.0_144/jre"
```